# Java: How to explicitly call the own classes version of a method?

Tags: java, syntax

Consider this MWE:

```java
public class Base {
  public int myRecursiveAlgo(int a) {
     if (a == 0) { return 0; }
     return a + myRecursiveAlgo(a - 1);
  }
}

public class Child extends Base {
  public int myRecursiveAlgo(int a) {
    return super.myRecursiveAlgo(a) + 1; // modification
  }
}
```

Now, you see, the `Child::myRecursiveCall()` wants to adjust the end result by one. But, the `Base::myRecursiveAlgo()` is now broken by the fact that the recursive call is dispatched to `Child::myRecursiveAlgo()`. How can I explicitly call the `Base::myRecursiveAlgo()` from the Base class?

In C++, you can do `return a + Base::myRecursiveAlgo(a - 1);` to prevent calling the subclasses overriden variant of the method.

Comment: You cannot. At least not without changing `myRecursiveAlgo`'s implementation in `Base`. You could extract the body of `myRecursiveAlgo` in `Base` into a separate `final` method and call it from `myRecursiveAlgo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. There is no way.

Therefore, any code you write that invokes one of your own methods needs to do one of these things, or your code is broken in a not-yet-testable way (i.e. a disaster waiting to happen, very bad):

- The method you're about to invoke needs to be `private`, or package private and sufficiently documented that all those operating within the same package know about the required properties of it.
- Alternatively, the method must be made `final`, or your class needs to be effectively `final` (if it is non-final but all constructors are `private`, it is effectively final - any overloads can only occur by writing child/siblings in the same source file and presumably anybody writing there is aware of the conditions or at least responsible for adhering to them).
- Alternatively, your method will not rely on any properties it has, or, alternatively, the properties it relies upon are at least documented, with a caveat emptor.
- Alternatively, have your overridable method be a one-liner that farms out the work to a non-overridable one (e.g. a private one and/or a final one). There where you require the properties locked in specifically to your base implementation, call the helper. Of course, this is confusing in its own right: Presumably if someone decides to override the method, it's odd that their override isn't invoked at all in certain cases.

That third one (document it, and pray) does exist - for example, you are free to write a inconsistent equals/hashCode algorithm for some class and then use instances of that class as keys in a HashMap, but the result will be bizarroland, with various methods of Map outright lying, and weird exceptions occuring at unexpected times. That's, presumably, on the shining light that decided to not read up on the contract requirements for equals/hashCode.

You can do the same thing if you must.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I couldn't find any info online. I'll use `myRecursiveAlgo0` as private function that does the actual work.